# Generate .dll from Application Project in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, dll

I've got an Application Project (C++) in NetBeans. When I build it, it generates the .exe program. Is there a way to generate a .dll instead, or do I have to create a Dynamic Library project and copy everything I've done into it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Goto "Project Properties" on the project.
2. Select "Build" on the left.
3. Click on "Configuration Type" and pick "Dynamic library".

You can also add a new configuration for building dynamic libraries by pressing the Manage configurations button.